# Custom Comment Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, comments

I have created a custom post type for a sort of gallery whereby users can upload work etc. In addition to this I have taxonomies for this type such as categories, tags, colors, etc.

But I want users to be able to do two things. a) comment b) critique.

As far as I know WordPress doesn't support Custom Comment Types so I can't create the critique comments, any ideas on how I could do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please don't confuse terms.  Custom Post Types is a mis-named feature that should really be Custom *Content* Types.  They're pieces of content that aren't posts or pages, but live in the same kind of database.  Like posts and pages, they can have tags, categories, comments, and other custom meta and taxonomies applied.

However, comments are still comments, whether they're on a post, page, or "gallery" in your situation.  So here's my counter-question: what is different between comments and critiques in your scenario?

If they're fundamentally similar, I'd recommend *not*  distinguishing between them.  If they're fundamentally different, try this:

Set up "critiques" as its own custom post type.  Then either associate critiques with galleries using a custom taxonomy or by storing the ID of the gallery/piece being critiqued in a custom field of the critique.  This will make it easy to find critiques for specific galleries/pieces in the future while still keeping them distinct from comments.

Comment: The difference is comments would be just quick feedback (if feedback at all), they may just be some kind words. Where as critique can only be posted by a certain role and will involve much more content like say a full review. But in hindsight they will be very similar to comments. I like the idea of custom posts as they will allow me to control access etc. Just not sure about linking up a critique to a post as snug as a comment is to a post.

Comment: It won't be as "snug" but if a critique is as rich in terms of content as you're describing, a custom post type is the best way to go.

Comment: @Cameron: The `attachment` post type uses the `post_parent` database field to link to the `post` or `page` that contains this attachment. So it would not be uncommon to use this field too to link a `critique` custom post type to and `artwork` custom post type.

Answer (score -1):

I find the way to create my own comment type, but it isn't a nice solution.

I have now (except comment, pingback and trackback) also review, curio and article.
Visually look almost the same, but I don't want to have custom fields; only different types.

So, in this way : `?p=15#comments` I get normal comments list, and for ex. `?p=15?reviews#comments` I get only comments, where post_type (in wp_posts) is like 'review'.

There was some changes in source files in `wp-includes` and theme comment file, so if someone is interesting how to do that then I can explain the way ;)

Comment: This answer is not very useful unless you explain exactly how you made this work.

Comment: I agree with @s_ha_dum - care to share your edits and why it's not a 'nice' solution?