# How do I associate a custom post type with another through a taxonomy or storing an ID in a custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm working this problem discussed here:  [Custom Comment Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/custom-comment-types/4796#4796), but I need more clues to map out the process.  I want to create custom post types and associations between Questions & Answers, and Pin-ups & Critiques.  I think that I want to do this because I want to be able to archive and create feeds for Answers and Critiques separate from Post Comments  For example, for a given author/user home page, I want to be able to list Questions posed, Answers given, work Pinned-up for comment, and Critiques made.  An Answer would include the title of the Question it refers to.  This is more of an aside, but I am imagining a role/capability to comment on each custom post type (Question, Answer, etc. ala Quora and Stack Exchange).  The comment referenced 2 options:  using a custom taxonomy and storing an ID in a custom field.  I'm self-learning, so any additional help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've explored both options, using custom fields and a custom taxonomy, in previous versions of my plugin, [Posts 2 Posts](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts). The latest version uses two custom tables.

Comment: why do you find using cutom tables better the postmeta or terms table?

Comment: postmeta => slow queries; terms => can't add info per connection